# python how to print the authURL from the responde url

Tags: python, printing

[i have this in html responde](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hryni.jpg)[How i can print the authURL value from the responde](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fDBW.png)

```
"authURL" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

Comment: Could you show us your code? So we can help you.

Comment: Please avoid uploading code as an image.
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: img : https://ibb.co/cNDnnnd